# What does require.define mean in the snippet below?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd

I am trying to write an embeddable extenstion for our service such that people can import it via `<script src"/my/cds/path.js"></script>`. As an example I have been looking at Stripe [checkout](https://stripe.com/ca).js implementation. The snippet below is part of the code that loads from Stripe CDN when I add StripeCheckout into a script tag in my index.html.

```
    (function() {
    var namespace = "StripeCheckout.require".split("."),
        name = namespace[namespace.length - 1],
        base = this,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < namespace.length - 1; i++) { base = base[namespace[i]] = base[namespace[i]] || {} }
    if (base[name] === undefined) {
        base[name] = function() {
            var modules = {},
                cache = {};
            var requireRelative = function(name, root) {
                var path = expand(root, name),
                    indexPath = expand(path, "./index"),
                    module, fn;
                module = cache[path] || cache[indexPath];
                if (module) { return module } else if (fn = modules[path] || modules[path = indexPath]) {
                    module = { id: path, exports: {} };
                    cache[path] = module.exports;
                    fn(module.exports, function(name) { return require(name, dirname(path)) }, module);
                    return cache[path] = module.exports
                } else { throw "module " + name + " not found" }
            };
            var expand = function(root, name) {
                var results = [],
                    parts, part;
                if (/^\.\.?(\/|$)/.test(name)) { parts = [root, name].join("/").split("/") } else { parts = name.split("/") }
                for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) { part = parts[i]; if (part == "..") { results.pop() } else if (part != "." && part != "") { results.push(part) } }
                return results.join("/")
            };
            var dirname = function(path) { return path.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/") };
            var require = function(name) { return requireRelative(name, "") };
            require.define = function(bundle) { for (var key in bundle) { modules[key] = bundle[key] } };
            require.modules = modules;
            require.cache = cache;
            return require
        }.call()
    }
})();
```

and then follows by multiple snippets similar to this:

```
StripeCheckout.require.define({
 "lib/spellChecker": function(exports, require, module) {
    (function() {
        var levenshtein;
        module.exports = {
                levenshtein: levenshtein = function(str1, str2) {
                },
                suggest: function(dictionary, badword, threshold) {
                }
        }
    }).call(this)
   }
});
```

**Question**:

1. Am I wrong to say that the first snippet is defining require.define() and next is making use of that? Is this a way to simulate require.js?
2. Where is require.define() coming from? If it is require.js what is it doing?
3. How would one go about hosting a whole package on a CDN such that different modules are accessible via the JS code on-client for loading like above? (I don't see Stripecheckout.js being anything other than one JS file. Where are other files?)

I have read about JS [modules](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc) and [requireJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) documentation but I think I need some clarification.

Comment: Define is a function of `require.js` and it defines a module "lib\spellchecker" the module exports an object with 2 properties, `levenshtein` and `suggest`

Comment: thanks for the reply, are you saying that "lib\spellchecker" doesnt exist on their CDN and its being defined right there? why would you need to use require.js then? I'm gonna go through the require.js sgain, thanks